# How to fetch HTTPS web resurce with HttpClient 4.5.2 & JDK 1.8 when server uses Server Name Indication (SNI) extension?

Tags: java, https, httpclient, apache-httpcomponents, sni

I can't fetch resources from SNI sites with HttpClient. URLs I am trying to fetch are: https://dabar.srce.hr/, https://www.lutrija.hr/cms/splash.

I get this error:
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

As I understand the documentation it should work like this out of the box (and it works for non sni https sites):

```
url = "https://dabar.srce.hr/";
SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {
    // trust all certificates
    public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
        return true;
    }
}).build();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSF = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslSF).build();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
```

I tried to explicitly enable SNIExtension:

```
System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "true");
```

I tried overriding SSLConnectionSocketFactory:

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSF = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE) {
    String targetHost = "";
    @Override
    public Socket createLayeredSocket(Socket socket, String target, int port, HttpContext context)
                throws IOException {
        this.targetHost = target;
        return super.createLayeredSocket(socket, target, port, context);
    }
    @Override
    protected void prepareSocket(SSLSocket socket) throws IOException {
        try {
            PropertyUtils.setProperty(socket, "host", this.targetHost);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        super.prepareSocket(socket);
    }
    @Override
    public Socket connectSocket(int connectTimeout, Socket socket, HttpHost host, InetSocketAddress remoteAddress, InetSocketAddress localAddress, HttpContext context) 
        throws IOException {
        if (socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
            try {
                PropertyUtils.setProperty(socket, "host", host.getHostName());
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        }
    }
    return super.connectSocket(connectTimeout, socket, host, remoteAddress,
                    localAddress, context);
    }
};
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. This custom SSLConnectionSocketFactory fixed it for me:

```
public class TrustAllSslSocketFactory extends SSLConnectionSocketFactory {

    static final HostnameVerifier ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER = (String hostname, SSLSession session) -> true;

    public TrustAllSslSocketFactory(SSLContext sslContext) {
        super(sslContext, ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void prepareSocket(SSLSocket socket) throws IOException {
                String hostName = socket.getInetAddress().getHostName();
        SNIHostName sniHostName = new SNIHostName(hostName);
        List serverNames = new ArrayList(1);
        serverNames.add(sniHostName);
        SSLParameters sslParameters = socket.getSSLParameters();
        sslParameters.setServerNames(serverNames);
        socket.setSSLParameters(sslParameters);
    }


}
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SNIExamples

Comment: The overridden prepareSocket() method is pointless because a HostnameVerifier that always returns true will allow any hostname.