Apache HTTP Client SSL via custom servername SNI
I have a Apache Async Http client which I use to connect to IP addresses (instead of domain name). I want to find a way to provide the SNI information, something like this so that the SSL handshake can happen with the correct certificate.
I have tried to build something with PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager and SSLIOSessionStrategy etc, but I don't see any option to provide the servername to the http client and make a CloseableHttpAsyncClient object. Any help will be appreciated!
An example would be to connect to an endpoint with something like openssl s_client -connect 1.2.3.4:443 -servername ab.cd.com. If I don't use the raw IP address to connect (instead use the full domain name), the SNI handling works fine with the client but I am not able to use IP address and custom servername information together using the Apache HTTP Async client (4.1.3 is the version  I was trying).
I have tried to go through the Apache HTTP Client code and find a class which I can override or optionally provide the servername field. I see that it is probably required while creating the SSLSocket or SSLEngine and could be provided as part of SSLContext, but I am not finding a way to add servername via some override.

SNI is used to support multiple virtual hosts at a single IP address. Why would you need to use it to hold an IP address? Would you be sending a different IP address in the SNI field than you are connecting to?

You might have to construct a custom SSLConnectionSocketFactory for use with the Apache client.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807435/how-to-fetch-https-web-resurce-with-httpclient-4-5-2-jdk-1-8-when-server-uses

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I would be sending a domain name in the servername field. If some IP hosts 2 different domain names, I want to distinguish using the servername.

@AndrewHenle The CloseableHttpAsyncClient from httpasyncclient-4.1.3.jar doesn't have the set ssl factory function. It has the option to set SSLContext and SSLStrategy but I haven't been able to find a way to provide servername in one of these.

@abs060: I see, it's just the normal use of SNI. I don't know what made me think otherwise.

I will try this solution as this conversation seems to suggest the HttpHost might be getting used for SNI servername.
